# How to compile ASP from SP Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, asp.net, html

I am previewing an `aspx` page in SP Designer 2013. It's not loading any of my content and not generating the HTML I'm looking for because the ASP is not being compiled.

How can I run this code through SP Designer 2013?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "is not being compiled" ? If you're somehow referring to code-behind or inline code, this is plainly not possible in SP Designer

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint Designer you can create an `aspx` page. This page does not create a corresponding `cs` file as `Visual Studio` does.

The code behind file you can create using `Visual Studio` and compile into a class library. Deploy the library into GAC. And then you can update the Reference Tags on the `aspx` page.

```
<%@ Page 
Language="C#" 
DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" 
Inherits="Namespace.PageClass, Assembly.AssemblyFullName"
%>
```